# ActionBar not splitting after show

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, android-view

I hide the action bar first using below

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

where for this activity i have `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` but later before the page loads i show the action bar by below

```
 getSupportActionBar().show();
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
                getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_home);
```

but the problem is the action bar is not splitting after i hide and then show it.

Comment: I've got the same problem. Did you manage to solve it?